# calculate GST in jQuery HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, calculation

I am trying to calculate the CGST/SGST/IGST based on `input#input`.
here I am considering `input#gst_rate = 18`.
actually, I am trying - if the user selects `LOCAL` then `input#gst_rate` will be divided into `2` and the value as `9` will show in `input#cgst = 9` and `input#sgst = 9` and `input#igst = 0`.

If the user selects `INTERSTAE` then `input#gst_rate` will show in `input#igst = 18` and `input#cgst = 0` and `input#sgst = 0`.

I am not familiar with javascript and jQuery. Please help me with how I achieve the code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="gst_type" class="gst_type" id="gst_type">
  <option value="1">LOCAL</option>
  <option value="2">INTERSTATE</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control  gst_rate" id="gst_rate" value="18">
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" class="form-control  cgst" id="cgst" placeholder="CGST">
<input type="text" class="form-control  sgst" id="sgst" placeholder="SGST">
<input type="text" class="form-control  igst" id="igst" placeholder="IGST">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could study this piece of code which shows the result you are waiting:

```js
// initialize
var init_value = $("#gst_rate").val();
var choice = 2
$("#gst_type").val(choice).trigger("change");
interstate();
display(choice);


function interstate() {
  $("#cgst").val(0);
  $("#sgst").val(0);
  $("#igst").val(init_value);
}
function local() {
  let newvalue = init_value / 2;
  $("#cgst").val(newvalue);
  $("#sgst").val(newvalue);
  $("#igst").val(0);
}

function display(c){
  if(c == 1){
    local();
  }else if(c == 2){
    interstate();
  }
}
$("#gst_rate").on("change", function() {
  init_value = $("#gst_rate").val();
  display(choice);
});

$("#gst_type").on("change", function() {
  choice = $(this).val();
  display(choice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="gst_type" class="gst_type" id="gst_type">
  <option value="1">LOCAL</option>
  <option value="2">INTERSTATE</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control  gst_rate" id="gst_rate" value="18">
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" class="form-control  cgst" id="cgst" placeholder="CGST">
<input type="text" class="form-control  sgst" id="sgst" placeholder="SGST">
<input type="text" class="form-control  igst" id="igst" placeholder="IGST">
```

Comment: but it is not dynamic when i changing the value of `#gst_rate` is not working it working only `18`

Comment: @Satyam i have modified the code to be more dynamic, when you chnage the value of rate, all values will be updated when you leave the rate

Comment: Please understand `18` was just for example. I want suppose if I enter `18` then `9` -`9` will show in each box , same if `5` then `2.5` - `2.5` in each box of `#cgst,#sgst`

Comment: @Satyam oh i understand the value of rate doesnt change..i missunderstood that..its fixed

Comment: not helpful. still not working as expected

Comment: @Satyam are you sure?, maybe you are testing during my modification, could you retest?  i have the result waited when i enter 18 or 5 when Local is selected

Comment: you say in local mode input#igst = 0. you confirm?

Comment: sir, please understand `5`,`28` should be any number.

Comment: sorry i dont understant when you enter any number in rate, at once you loose the focus, the values change?

Comment: actually, your updates and code are not run perfectly in StackOverflow output. When I use your code on my page it worked.

Comment: I am sorry but when I use your code in my function `function getGSTData(row_id) { YOUR CODE }` it not working. my case `#gst_type` is appended dynamically and I use like this `<select name="gst_type_update[]" class="form-control gst_type_update" id="gst_type_update_value_${items.slno}" onclick="getGSTData(${items.slno})"><option value="0">-- TYPE --</option><option value="1">LOCAL</option><option value="2">INTER STATE</option></select>`

Comment: `${items.slno}` is dynamic sequence number retrive from PHP json . please help me

Comment: its not the same problem and same approach...so you didnt say that your data was coming from php server..to avoid to pollute this answer/question could you set a new question (add tag php) and explain your new problem...and show your complete real code.. i try to help you but others people which know php could you help too

Comment: no, there is no issue in PHP I mean to say how I use the function method in your code. when I use this function `onclick="getGSTData(NUMBER)"` it not worked

Comment: ok i 'll look at this problem...its normal my code is not functional , its not the same approach..my event is outside the html and your event is inside..its the reason i say its not the same problem...

Comment: what is the the arg *${items.slno}* of function getGSTData?  a number? the rate data?

Comment: ${items.slino} = 'serial number of row. serial number bcz changes will happen in a select row.

Comment: i dont see the link between this arg and my code?

Comment: `https://jsfiddle.net/twt2shiv/qsvzjwka/10/` please see this I want to say like this.. I want if select box change the changes will affect in the selected row. I am storing the row id in `getGSTData(1,2,3) etc`.

Comment: ok i have found a solution, but the solution has nothing to do with your question here, its really another problem. please, i suggest you to post your new problem and show the code you have in fiddle and i give you explanation on tne new thread. its better to avoid mixture here to change everthing

Comment: the issue was from beginning but I just want to ask in break process. Please help me

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/Frenchy62620/mp5w4edn/   its the solution, you have to put off onclick inside html..

Comment: great! but how you do that ? I could see any row if in code to detect the row and inputs. is that code will work in appeded text box too?

Comment: i am using $(this)  to trap the right selector and you have put the rowid at the end of the id of the selector selected by event change.. i think you need to read some tutorial on jquery selector.!

Comment: can I do one change more if any data change all data also change, it may be on focus, onblue,onchnage anything, in your code it works only when dropdown changes.

Comment: when you change the value of rate, others values are updated when you quit the rate field, if you want to trap each change when you change rate, modify the event on *change* by on *input* . with *input* event , each change in field, change others fields.

Comment: sorry but your code is still not working in appended element

Comment: sir it is not working in appended text box

Comment: sorry i am lost, i  cant see your problem only by comment, expose totally your problem in another question with maximum details, because the code is functional in my snippets and not functional in your program so i cant guess where is your problem. As you see there are lot of comments, so there is a misunderstood on the way to understand where is your problem